# Get a listing of a 7zip file on a remote HTTP server

Tags: http, archiving, 7-zip

There's a server out there on the internet that hosts terabytes of data encapsulated in numerous 7zip (.7z) archives. Some, but not all, of this data is interesting to me. I only know which data is interesting if I can inspect the filenames in the archive.

**Question: How can I retrieve the listing of a 7zip file from the remote HTTP server, *without downloading the entire file first*?**

These archives range in size from a megabyte to a gigabyte, and I really don't want to waste time and bandwidth downloading an archive if it doesn't contain data that I can use.

*Addendum: I thought of a rather circuitous solution tot he problem, but I can't stop thinking that there has to be an easier solution and that surely other people have faced (or will face) this same problem.*

Comment: Most compressed files contain a directory within them, so if you can grab the first few bytes of the file (either by using HTTP Range requests or simply by closing the connection early), you'll have a malformed/incomplete 7z file, but might have enough data to extract the list of contents. I have no idea how to do this, though, which is why this is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: This is the solution I came up with as well. I wanted to see if there was an easier way. I guess not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a way to accomplish this on a system that supports [Filesystem in USErspace (FUSE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_in_Userspace). I am responding to my own question in case anyone has a need to accomplish the same thing.

There is a FUSE modules called [httpfs2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/httpfs/files/httpfs2/) that allows you to mount an HTTP URL to make it appear as if it's part of the local filesystem. The httpfs2 is able to fetch specific ranges of bytes from the remote server in response to file system read calls that a program makes.

To install this tool on Ubuntu Linux:

```
apt-get install httpfs2
```

Create a mount point on the file system:

```
mkdir mount-point
```

Mount the remote URL:

```
httpfs2 http://remote.server.tld/path/archive-file.7z mount-point
```

Now the file `archive-file.7z` looks like it's part of the filesystem:

```
ls mount-point/archive-file.7z
7za l mount-point/archive-file.7z
```

To unmount the directory:

```
fusermount -u mount-point
```

This approach will allow you to list the contents of any HTTP-hosted archive (using the correct archiving tool to list the contents) without downloading the entire (possibly huge) archive.

Answer (score 4):

There's no client-side method via just "HTTP" to facilitate what you're requesting.

So this isn't going to happen without the server providing you the list, which would require custom programming and/or manual work on the server's side to produce the list.

Comment: I figured there was no easy solution, but I thought I'd toss out the question anyway. I'll clean up and publish my really complicated solution in case anyone actually needs to do this.

Answer (score 0):

`httpfs2` just thrown various errors at me, such as `reply does not contain newline!` and didn't work.

I had success with https://github.com/fangfufu/httpdirfs

```
apt install httpdirfs
mkdir ~/Downloads/httpdirfs
httpdirfs -f --cache --dl-seg-size 1 https://example.com/path/to/folder/ ~/Downloads/httpdirfs
```

For some reason, `--single-file-mode` option is missing in Ubuntu 22.04, so I mounted entire folder instead of single file. I also used `--dl-seg-size 1` to avoid downloading unwanted content from a slow server.